# App Crashes when using setVisibility

Tags: java, android, xml

As the title says,

When using startLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
The app Crashes and I am not sure how to fix

The Java code below.

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {


private TextView  scoreLabel;
private TextView  startLabel;

private ImageView box;
private ImageView orange;
private ImageView pink;
private ImageView black;

// Position
private int boxY;
private int boxX;

// Initialize Class
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Timer timer = new Timer();

//Status Check
private boolean action_flg = false;
private boolean start_flg = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreLabel);
    scoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startLabel);

    box = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.box);
    orange = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.orange);
    pink = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pink);
    black = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.black);


    //Moves images to out of the screen
    //orange.setX(-80.0f);
    orange.setY(-80.0f);

   // pink.setX(-80.0f);
    pink.setY(-80.0f);

    //black.setX(-80.0f);
    black.setY(-80.0f);


     boxY = 200;

}

public void changePos()
{

    //Move box
    if (action_flg == true)
    {
        // touching
        boxY  -= 20;
    } else {
        //released
        boxY += 20;

    }
    box.setY(boxY);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
{

    if (start_flg == false)
    {
        start_flg = true;

        //Issue here with setting the visibility of the start
       // startLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        changePos();
                    }
                });
            }

            // Changing these numbers slows down how fast the box moves.
        }, 0, 100);
    }else {
        if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            action_flg = true;
        }else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            action_flg = false;
        }

    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Here is the XML version of the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="me.scott.nathan.catchtheball.Main">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Score : 300"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
  </TextView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tap to Start"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/box"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />

        <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/orange"
         android:layout_width="20dp"
         android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:src="@drawable/orange" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/black"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pink"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pink" />

    </FrameLayout>

<!--
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22" />
-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone help appreciated to fix this issue, Thanks

Comment: would be good to include your code within the post.

Comment: Your Java code is private

Comment: And the crash's stack trace

Comment: Added the code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your `startLabel` is null (copy paste problem?^^). Replace this:

```
scoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startLabel);
```

with this:

```
startLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startLabel);
```